# Use LINQ to populate controls from object array

Tags: c#, linq

I am just trying to find a better way to populate some RadioButtonList controls.  There are a set number of these on the usercontrol.ascx.  The code is what I am currently using but I am still not very good with Linq and was wondering if there's a better way to do this.

```
    quizId1 = quiz.Items[0].questionId;
    pTag1.InnerText = quiz.Items[0].QuestionText;
    foreach (Question q in quiz.Items[0].AnswerChoice)
    {
        radiobuttonlist1.Items.Add(new ListItem(q.Value, q.answerId));
    }
```

same for radiobuttonlist2 but using Items[1] etc.

```
    quizId2 = quiz.Items[1].questionId;
    pTag2.InnerText = quiz.Items[1].QuestionText;
    foreach (Question q in quiz.Items[1].AnswerChoice)
    {
        radiobuttonlist2.Items.Add(new ListItem(q.Value, q.answerId));
    }
```

Sorry, the InnerText is a server side 'P' tag, pTag1, pTag2 etc.

Comment: what are quizId1, quizId2 used for ? Where do you define radiobuttonlist1, radiobuttonlist2 ? The number of radionbuttonlist is defined ?

Comment: What do you hope to accomplish using LINQ? Just looking for a cleaner looking solution?

Comment: This is basically what `DataSource` is for, you can set that to be the result of your LINQ query rather than trying to update the list manually.

Comment: quizId1 etc is just a property to hold the ID for the specific Question and set of answers.  The controls are defined on the ascx using <asp:RadioButtonList> tags.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var listItems = (from x in quiz.Items[0].AnswerChoice
                          select new ListItem { Text = q.Value, Value = q.answerId }
                        ).ToList<ListItem>();

                radiobuttonlist1.DataSource = listItems;
                radiobuttonlist1.DataBind();
```

Comment: +1 only solution that uses the right tool for the job (i.e. `DataSource`).

Comment: Looks like it would work for the radiobuttonlist but I would still have to loop through for items[i] and I don't think I can set the quizId1, quizId2, pTag1, etc in the loop using items[i].

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to use ling to popiulate *several* controls, not *an individual* control.

Linq is for *querying*, not *updating*.  To update you still need either `for` or `foreach` loops.

If your `RadioButtonList` objects are in a collection, you could just loop over them:

```
var radioList = new [] {radiobuttonlist1, radiobuttonlist2, ...};
for(int i = 0; i < quiz.Items.Length; i++)
{
    var quizId = quiz.Items[i].questionId;
    radioList[i].InnerText = quiz.Items[i].QuestionText;
    radioList[i].Items.AddRange(quiz.Items[i]
                                    .AnswerChoice
                                    .Select(q => => new ListItem(q.Value, q.answerId))
                                    .ToArray()
                                );
}
```

or use `DataSource` as others have suggested:

```
var radioList = new [] {radiobuttonlist1, radiobuttonlist2, ...};
for(int i = 0; i < quiz.Items.Length; i++)
{
    var quizId = quiz.Items[i].questionId;
    radioList[i].InnerText = quiz.Items[i].QuestionText;
    radioList[i].DataSource = quiz.Items[i].AnswerChoice;
    radioList[i].DataTextField = "Value";
    radioList[i].DataValueField = "answerId";
}
```

but there's no Linq way to *populate* several controls.

Comment: Thanks, wasn't sure if I could populate multiple controls of the same type with Linq.  Only problem with the answer is quizId1, quizId2, pTag1, etc are the actual names so I can't use quizIdi to set the property.

Comment: @user3616982 That was't what I meant to suggest.  I meant to suggest using a variable _within the loop_ (see my edit).  Do you need `quizid1`, `quizid2`, etc. outside of this process?

Comment: yes I need to access quizId1 etc from another method.  the pTag1, pTag2 etc is a server side control I could load into another array like the radiobuttonlists.

Comment: Can you put _those_ values in an array?  `quizId = new [] {quizId1, quizId[2], etc.}`

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could do something like this:

```
var listItems = from q in quiz.Items[0].AnswerChoice
                select new ListItem(q.Value, q.answerId);
radioButtonlist1.Items.AddRange(listItems.ToArray());
```

though I'm not really sure if that buys you anything other than experience with LINQ...